# Solving a StackOverflow exception in a recursive relation

Tags: java, json

I have a recursive relationship between entities and at the moment my rest api converts it to JSON I get a StackOverflow exception, which I totally understand.

Jersey uses yasson as default JSON provider and I have found a solution where you can use @JsonbTransient to ignore a property in a object when serialized. My User-class has a list of Tweets and a Tweet has a user. So I added @JsonbTransient to my tweets list property in the User class.

**User-class:**

```
public class User {
    ...
    @JsonbTransient
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<Tweet> tweets;
    ...
}
```

**Tweet-class:**

```
public class Tweet {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

I want to render a list of all tweets (from different users) whilst accessing some properties on the related user. But I want to render the user with his list of tweets also on the same page (for getting tweets count etc.). Ignoring the tweets list on the user class isn't sufficient then.

Is there also an annotation that provides a way to serialize such a relation without completely ignoring a property on the first level, but on a deeper level.

For instance: When you know you are in a Tweet object that has a user, then the user ignores his tweet list and when the user isn't in a tweet object his tweet list will not be ignored. Or is this simply not possible?

How would someone tackle such a problem?

I could of course ignore the tweets list property in user and when I want the tweets of the corresponding user I retrieve them in another call. (not to be confused with lazy loading, because I want both the data at the start)

But my thought says that there might be a magical annotation that automatically solves this problem. Is it there?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding your API model too tightly to your database model. Don't do that.

Your API wants to return a model with a root user object with detailed information, including a list of tweets, and a tweet wants to identify the user, but doesn't want the *full* detailed user object, i.e. it just wants a user reference.

*Example:*

```
{
  "UserId": 1,
  "UserName": "Bob",
  "UserEmail": "bib@example.com",
  "Tweets": [
    {
      "User": {
        "UserId": 2,
        "UserName": "Alice",
      },
      "Text": "Hello Bob"
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the inner user object is a `MiniUser`, and the outer user object is a `FullUser` *(arbitrary names, you'd likely want to call them something else)*.

So, create the API model from the DAO model. Don't make the DAO model *be* the API model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That sounds pretty logical indeed. This also applies to the Tweet model itself, right? So, when a list of Tweets are retrieved from the database, I must then loop through it to convert it to a tweet api model list? And why doesn't this problem occur (StackOverflow) before serializing it to JSON, because the objects in memory also do have the circular reference?

Comment: @Maikkeyy `Tweet.user` is EAGER by default, and you made `User.tweets` EAGER too, so you may end up loading a huge chunk of your database into memory. You should make one of them LAZY. Anyway, it doesn't go infinite depth, because it'll only load each user once, unlike the JSON, which will expand forever. E.g. Bob tweets "Hi" to Alice, who tweets "Hello" to Bob. Database load stops there since Bob is already in memory. However, JSON will be: Bob tweets "Hi" to Alice, who tweets "Hello" to Bob, who tweets "Hi" to Alice, who tweets "Hello" to Bob, who ... `StackOverflowException`